# useEffect infinite loop WITH empty dependency array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am dispatching a thunk from my useEffect to populate a table when the page loads. The useEffect keeps running infintely, even though I am using an empty dependency array. Here is my code:

```
const Cart = (props) => {
  const [didFetch, setDidFetch] = useState(false);
  useEffect( () => {
    async function fetchCart(){
      await props.getCartItems();
      setDidFetch(true);
    }
    fetchCart()
    return setDidFetch(false)
  },[]);

  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }} aria-label="simple table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Product</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Quantity</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Total Cost</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {props.cartItems.map((item) => (
            <TableRow
              key={item.product.name}
              sx={{ "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": { border: 0 } }}
            >
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {item.product.name}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{item.quantity}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">
                {(item.quantity * item.product.price).toFixed(2)}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell>
                <Button onClick={() => props.removeCartItem(item.id)}>
                  Remove
                </Button>
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
};
```

Comment: You are returning a function call in your effect. You should return a function which then calls your `setDidFetch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanup function of `useEffect` should be an anonymous function, and you shouldn't set state variables inside it, as @windmaomao pointed out, it is a memory leak:

#### Suggestion

If you want to store a `didFetch` flag, I would use a ref for this purpose:

```
import {useRef} from 'react'

const Cart = (props) => {
  const fetched = useRef()
  useEffect( () => {
    async function fetchCart(){
      const res = await props.getCartItems();
      if(res) fetched.current = true
    }
    fetchCart()
    return () => fetched.current = false
  },[]);

  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }} aria-label="simple table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Product</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Quantity</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Total Cost</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {props.cartItems.map((item) => (
            <TableRow
              key={item.product.name}
              sx={{ "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": { border: 0 } }}
            >
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {item.product.name}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{item.quantity}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">
                {(item.quantity * item.product.price).toFixed(2)}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell>
                <Button onClick={() => props.removeCartItem(item.id)}>
                  Remove
                </Button>
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
};
```

Comment: you can't have a `setDidFetch` in the destroy of effect, it's a memory leak, just remove it. You don't need to set any state upon destroy.

Comment: @windmaomao just noticed that, editing the answer. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: not a problem, your solution looks good now. Although there's no usage of the `current` in his code.

Comment: OP doesn't use the `didFetch` in the question, I noticed that too. However, I figured OP would want to use it somewhere :)

Comment: I was reading somewhere that there can be weird bugs if you don't return a cleanup function to undo any changes you made. However, I don't really believe its necessary here, so I'll just take it out. Just to clarify, was that return statement creating the infinite loop? 

Also @windmaomao thats *her* code ;)

Thanks everybody!

Comment: You need cleanup functions to call like `() => /* do stuff*/` if you have async stuff going on in your useEffect, just so that if your component unmounts in the middle of the async function, you don't have memory leaks. That was the issue. If you find this helpful, please accept it as answer :) Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Using your existing code it would be either:

**Anonymous function**

```
  const [didFetch, setDidFetch] = useState(false);
  useEffect( () => {
    async function fetchCart(){
      await props.getCartItems();
      setDidFetch(true);
    }
    fetchCart()
    return () => { 
        setDidFetch(false); 
    };
  },[]);
```

**Named Function**

```
  const [didFetch, setDidFetch] = useState(false);
  useEffect( () => {
    async function fetchCart(){
      await props.getCartItems();
      setDidFetch(true);
    }
    fetchCart()
    return function cleanup() { 
        setDidFetch(false); 
    };
  },[]);
```

Here are the useEffect docs for reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html